# Where can I find the Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

I do not have an update manager, how can I reinstall it?
I clicked the gear and searched "Update Manager" and nothing comes up. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app called "Update Manager" in Ubuntu 12.04 has been renamed "Software Updater" since Ubuntu 12.10. To launch it, open the Dash Menu and search for "Software Updater".